# Why is this data handling code not working?

Tags: c++, file-handling

This code should display "abc123" but instead, some non-recognisable letters are displayed

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<fstream>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<string.h>
   using namespace std;
   int main()
   {
    fstream fin("rabbit.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
    fin.seekg(0);
    char arr[100]= "abc123 abc abc ejgrjgn ejrog rge k abc";
    char a[100];
    fin<<arr<<'\n';
    fin.seekg(0);
    char ch;
    fin.get(ch);
    fin.seekg(0);
    fin>>a;
    cout<< a;
   }
```

Comment: Could you narrow down the error to a specific section or point?

Comment: Did you flush the stream, before reading?

Comment: fin.get(ch);
Should this^ flush the stream?

Comment: Also, there is no error in the code. There is a logical error that I am not able to find

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for errors:

```
fstream fin("rabbit.txt",ios::in|ios::out);
if ( fin.is_open() )
{
    fin.seekg(0);
    char arr[100]= "abc123 abc abc ejgrjgn ejrog rge k abc";
    char a[100];
    fin<<arr<<'\n';
}
else
{
    cout<<"failed to open fstream\n";
}
```

You need ios::app or ios::trunc to create and open a file.